# Creating a condition using a dropdown menu for SELECT in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement

How do i create a condition that makes searching easy.

for example in the drop down, i selected Fruits.

SELECT * basket where type='fruits';

and when i change it to Vegetables

select * basket where type='vegetables';

how do i create a condition like that using select

here are my full codes

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <LINK href="admin_tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<font face="Calibri">
    <div align="right" style="padding-right:100px";>
        <form action="form.php" method="post" target="frame"> 
    <label>View by: </label>
    <select name="source">
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="All") ?>>All</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="Product Brands") ?>>Product Brands</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="Category") ?>>Category</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="Search Here" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    <button type='submit'><a href='CMS.php'>Add a New Product</a></button>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
<?php
session_start();
    $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");

$qry = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
echo "<center>";
echo "<table class='CSSTableGenerator'>
<tr>

<td>Product ID</td>
<td>Product Brand</td>
<td>Product Category</td>
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Action</td>
<tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['prod_id'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_brand'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_category'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_name'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_quantity'];
echo "<td> <center><button type='submit'><a href='update_inv.php?id=".$row['prod_id']."'>Edit</a></button>
           <button type='submit'><a href='delete_inv.php?id=".$row['prod_id']."'>Delete</a></button>
           <button type='submit'><a href='DISPLAY_PROD_PIC_SAMPLE.php?prod_id=".$row['prod_id']."'>View</a></button></center>";  
echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>



</body
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to make a For each loop. And `echo` the `<option>$row['yourcolumnname']</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that uses the value of the selected option in a function upon submission of the form. At the top of the php file, check the condition if the form has been submitted, then query if it has been submitted. It will probably look something like this:

```
    <?php // Variables
    // Defaults
    $sort_by = "name";
    $sort_method = "ASC";

    // Dynamic Values
    if (isset($_GET["sort"])) {
        $sort_by = $_GET["sort"];
        }
    if (isset($_GET["order"])) {
        $sort_method = $_GET["order"];
        }
?>
```

And then your form needs to be placed somewhere in the body tag:

```
<form method="get">
<select name="source" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="type">Type</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then query the results:

```
<?php
            // Query Corresponding Basket
            $query  = "SELECT * ";
            $query .= "FROM basket ";
            $query .= "WHERE brand_id = '{$sort_by}' ";
            $query .= "ORDER BY {$sort_by} {$sort_method} ";

            $product_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_set)){
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $result["name"];
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
```